# how to replace text when a user type text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm working on a user mention function now. I have a problem that I can't replace text

If I'm trying to find a user with "@" I can't find a user so that's why I replace text.

```
  const handleInputComment = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setCommentValue({ ...commentValue, comment: e.target.value });

    e.target.value.split(" ").map((text) => {
      if (text.startsWith("@")) {
        text.replace("@", "");
        setMentionSearchValue(text);
        console.log(mentionSearchValue);
        return setIsMentionModalOpen(true);
      }
      return setIsMentionModalOpen(false);
    });
  };
```

when I see the console.log what I will see like
@asdfsdf @sadfasfsaf @asdfjaskfjfkjf

how to replace text? thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do that instead:

```
  const handleInputComment = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setCommentValue({ ...commentValue, comment: e.target.value });

    e.target.value.split(" ").map((text) => {
      if (text.startsWith("@")) {
        setMentionSearchValue(text.replace("@", ""));
        console.log(mentionSearchValue);
        return setIsMentionModalOpen(true);
      }
      return setIsMentionModalOpen(false);
    });
  };
```

Replace returns the text replaced and it doesn't update the variable. To the text variable was not being updated.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript String Replace function is immutable, hence it won't change the value of text itself, rather, it will return a new value. But the problem with replace is it will replace all the occurances, if you are interested to get rid of the first `@` only, you can use `slice` method. Another issue is, you are printing the value of state right after calling setState i.e. `setMentionSearchValue`, but setState is an asynchronous function, so you won't see the new value in the console immediately after calling setState. If you want to print it's value after `mentionSearchValue` gets updated, you need to use `useEffect` hook.

```js
const handleInputComment = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setCommentValue({ ...commentValue, comment: e.target.value });

  e.target.value.split(" ").map((text) => {
    if (text.startsWith("@")) {
      // text.replace("@", "");
      setMentionSearchValue(text.slice(1));
      // console.log(mentionSearchValue);
      return setIsMentionModalOpen(true);
    }
    return setIsMentionModalOpen(false);
  });
};
```